# Implementing addition for a custom class

Tags: python

I've got a class, `A`, which carries some data in dictionaries.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, names: set) -> None:
        self.d = {name : list() for name in names}
```

I am looking to define addition for my class, for which I want to return another instance of `A` with the combined contents of the dictionaries of the two instances of `A`.

I get that I need define the `__add__` method, but since I only want the addition to be defined for the `A` type, I first want to check that they match types. Ideally I'd want to do this with a `try except for readability, but I've heard that I'm supposed to use an ordinary if statement. I've also got some issues with the TypeError I'm raising, it's coming out weird.

```
    def __add__(self, a2):
        if type(self) == type(a2):
            # add functionality later
            pass 
        else:
            raise TypeError
```

This is what the addition looks like when it isn't working:

```
A({'a'}) + 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    A({'a'}) + 2
  File "C:...test.py", line 20, in __add__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

My question is:

Can/should this be done with a try except instead, and should I not be raising a TypeError?

Comment: You'd probably want to raise an actual instance of a type error, say `raise TypeError(f"{self} can't be added to {a2}")`...

Comment: And using a try/except is really kind of up to you and what the class actually does. If you don't have a strict type guard (like you do now), your type will happily work with dict-esque types too, which could well be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to say this should always be implemented this way, But I usually do this:

1. Instead of `type`, I use `isintance()` to cover the inheritance. The instances of the subclass of `A`, ***are*** `A`.
2. I return `NotImplemented` object so that maybe the other object had implemented `__radd__`. If the other object didn't implement `__radd__`, you will get a meaningful `TypeError` message. Python does that for you. Returning `NotImplemented` object is the [recommended approach](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-7):

> ...**Numeric methods** and rich comparison methods **should** return this value
> if they do not implement the operation for the operands provided.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, names: set) -> None:
        self.d = names

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, A):
            return NotImplemented
        return A(self.d | other.d)


class B:
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print("radd called")

class C:
    pass


obj1 = A({1})
obj2 = A({2})
obj3 = B()
obj4 = C()

print(obj1 + obj2) # calls A.__add__
print(obj1 + obj3) # calls B.__radd__
print(obj1 + obj4) # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'C'
```

Comment: Actually even the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) for Python state you *should* return `NotImplemented`.

Answer (score 2):

You should raise an instance of TypeError with a meaningful description of the error. You can then catch that and emit the description.

You probably want something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, names: set) -> None:
        self.d = {name : [] for name in names}
    def __add__(self, n):
        if isinstance(n, type(self)):
            # do something with n and return a new instance of A
            return A(set(self.d))
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Invalid parameter for add [{type(n)}]')

try:
    a = A({'a'}) + 'b'
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid parameter for add [<class 'str'>]
```

Comment: I don't think `return self` is actually desired here. `__iadd__` is supposed to be in-place operation, `__add__` is not.

Comment: @matszwecja Thank you. I was thinking of iadd. Code corrected (I think)